# datapicker на мобильной версии

Tags: css, jquery-ui, datepicker

при разрешении 615х862 и ниже datepicker полностью рушится все дни просто идут в один столбец, как сделать что бы на мобильных устройствах вызывался родной календарь или хотя бы этот не рушился, не понятно почему он себя так ведет, заметил что никто с такой проблемой не сталкивался

```
  $(function() {

        $.datepicker.regional['ru'] = {
            monthNames: ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Янв', 'Фев', 'Мар', 'Апр', 'Май', 'Июн', 'Июл', 'Авг', 'Сен', 'Окт', 'Ноя', 'Дек'],
            dayNames: ['Понедельник', 'Вторник', 'Среда', 'Четверг', 'Пятница', 'Суббота', 'Воскресенье'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Пнд', 'Втр', 'Срд', 'Чтв', 'Птн', 'Сбт', 'Вск'],
            dayNamesMin: ['Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб', 'Вс']
        };

        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['ru']);

        $('#from, #to').datepicker({
            showMonthAfterYear: false,

            // dateFormat: "dd M yy",
            numberOfMonths: 2
        });

    });
```

подключение в теме header.php (wordpress)

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: А код ваш мы должны угадывать? Это кастинг на битву экстрасенсов?

Comment: прошу прощение, код добавил